# How to access static files from inside Wordpress plugin directory

Tags: php, wordpress, flash, plugins

I'm trying to create a custom Wordpress Plugin for one of my websites. And I've created a shortcode inside the plugin and I have one .swf file inside the plugin directory that I want to embed using the created shortcode. I've tried with `<embed src="wp-content/plugins/myplugin/obj.swf">` also tried with `<iframe>` but I get 404 Page not found error. The same error when I try to open the swf file directly from the browser's address bar. Can anyone give me little hand how can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: "The same error when I try to open the swf file directly" - what URL are you using?  Plugin files should be accessible.  For example, I can see http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=3.9 in one of my client's sites

Comment: For example here is the swf object I'm talking about but it cannot be founded http://www.lajmislam.com/wp-content/plugins/falja-e-namazit-wp/falja.swf

Comment: Ok, but your plugins directory is accessible - I can see (for example) http://www.lajmislam.com/wp-content/plugins/quran-text-multilanguage/js/soundmanager.js?ver=4.4.2 in the source of your home page.  So either you haven't uploaded your plugin, or you have the path wrong, or you're looking at the wrong server. But being able to see that directory structure doesn't depend on WordPress - if your path is correct, you should be able to see it with the URL you just posted.  Can you edit your question with a screen grab of your /wp-content/plugins/falja-e-namazit-wp folder (on the server)?

Comment: Ok, I've just updated the question with screenshot from folder structure. I am trying to access it from falja-namazit-wp.php

Comment: Aha - it's case sensitive.  I can access http://www.lajmislam.com/wp-content/plugins/falja-e-namazit-WP/falja.swf (note the capital WP in the folder name)

Comment: ok, I'm able to access it right now but I don't know how to deal for example if I place the swf file into a sub-directory for example /assets/falja.swf it gives me incorrect url.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you mean, but I've updated my answer to work out the URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on our comments, and the screen shot, you should rename the folder on the server to be in lower case (ie from `falja-e-namazit-WP` to `falja-e-namazit-wp`).

**EDIT**

Not sure what you mean by your latest comment, but you should be able to get the URL of your asset using the [`plugins_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url#Common_Usage) function.  Assuming your SWF file is in `/wp-content/plugins/falja-e-namazit-wp/assets`, the following code (in `/wp-content/plugins/falja-e-namazit-wp/falja-e-namazit-wp.php`) should return its URL:

```
$swf_url = plugins_url( 'assets/falja.swf', __FILE__ );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very precise and constructive help. I was looking for functions like plugins_url() you mentioned about. Thank you again

Comment: No worries - glad I was able to help